# How to get compression type of a PCL print file?

Tags: spool, pclxl

How do you know what compression method is used for the data in a .pcl file? like below?   it doesn't start with ESC in the actual data block.

%-12345X@PJL JOB NAME="page count pcl.txt - Notepad"
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=PCLXL
) HP-PCL XL;2;0;Comment Copyright (c) 2001 Software 2000 Limited
ÑXXø‰ÀøÀ
ø†AÀ

Comment: Set the spooler to print direct.  Set your port to print to file.  Read it with a hex editor.  Thats what I used to do when I wrote PCL drivers.. should still work.

Comment: Do you know when you right mouse properties on a print job in the spool queue and it pulls up the printer driver with settings for the print job. where does it get the print job driver information from?  I can see from procmon.exe it calls a driver dll which has JCDisposeInterface and JCGetInterface, but there's no file open of the spl.   Ultimately what I'm trying to do is get the printjob tray name information from all the print jobs in the queue. (I can get this from the driver but not from prints in the queue)

Comment: ignore that, worked it out. by getting devmode from getjob